# inverse kinematics rigging on a quadruped

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics, surface-deform

im learning to rig a quadruped and i want my IK to be able to bend 2 different ways. usually i could solve this by playing around with the pole angle but that seems to deform the mesh in an unwanted way

[image]
[image]

i did find a way to swap between the 2 ways interchangeably but that requires going into edit mode and moving where the 2 bones connect and making a separate rig for each possibility (about 24) and i dont want to do that.

[image]
[image]
[image]

this model will only be used for posing in images and not for animations at all if that info can help in any way

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g2BvC0eyAvy5Qcc0BR-rc_LAoDV0Gj2a/view?usp=sharing)

EDIT: rotating the calf bone does this. its a step in the right direction but the paw is backwards and there is some of that twist deformation

[image]

and when i put copy rotation of ik controller onto the paw, it looks like a balloon animal
[image]

Comment: You don't have to change in edit (and shouldn't); you can rotate the calf bone in pose mode, such that it's pre-IK bend goes in the other direction.  Might be useful to disable the IK while you do this, the first time, so you can see what's happening.

Comment: edited post. i may not be following your steps correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that IK bones bend is a function of how they bend, before the IK is evaluated.  This is why changing the position of bones in edit mode changes the IK: it changes the bend.  Because your armature's calf bends forward from the thigh in rest pose, it continues to bend forward from the thigh as the IK target is manipulated:

[image]

However, like I said, it's the **pre-IK** bend that matters.  That doesn't have to be the rest pose, not if we rotate the calf.  Let's turn off IK briefly so we can see what we're doing, then rotate the calf in its Z axis (here) to reverse the bend:

[image]

Now, when we turn the IK back on, we'll see that the direction of the bend has reversed:

[image]

Anytime we want, we can clear the rotation on the calf bone to return it to its rest-pose bend.

We don't actually need to turn off the IK to do this.  Provided we're careful about the axes in which we rotate the calf, we can rotate it while leaving the IK live.

This is something to be careful of when animating, because when we switch the direction of the bend, we'll have discontinuous IK solutions unless the limb is fully extended.  But since you're only worried about stills, you don't have to worry about that.